# Report builder 2.0 expression to sort values highest to lowest on a chart

Tags: sql-server-2008, sorting, expression, reportbuilder3.0

I have a 3d cylinder chart that I am having some problems with. I want to effectively sort the cylinders with the highest value at the back and the lowest value at the front. Otherwise the tallest valuest cover the smallest values.

I have tried sorting both a-z and z-a but I really need it to be dynamic based on the values. I have also tried sorting the values by the actual value field. both a-z and z-a but this seems to return completely random results.

the data in the database (example) looks like. I use a parameter to separate by supplier.

```
Date       catgeory_Type  cost    supplier
01/01/2013   apple        $5       abc
01/01/2013   pear        $10       def
01/01/2013   bannana        $15    cgi
01/02/2013   apple        $7       etc
01/02/2013   pear        $12       etc
01/02/2013   banana        $18     etc
```

I believe I need some form of expression that sorts the values based on cost. as both a-z and z-a in the instance would provide cylinders that blocked other cylinders.

I have tried sorting the series group by  :=Sum(Fields!cost.Value, "DataSet1") and =Fields!cost.Value but this seems to return random results.

I would be happy even if I could achieve a custom sort such as sort by "bannana, pear, apple" although for some "suppliers" this would still cause me an issue.

edit 1: strangely enough this works with a line chart but not a 3d cylinder

edit 2: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeldC.jpg)

attached is an example. I want the tallest cylinders at the back. but methods mentioned above do not work

Comment: Please add a screenshot if possible. Question is not clear.

Comment: have added as requested

Answer (score 0):

In chart area properties -> 3D-options  , Enable,

**series clustering**

> Choose this option to cluster series groups. When multiple series for
>   bar or column charts are clustered, they are displayed along two
>   distinct rows in the chart area. If series are not clustered, their
>   corresponding data points are displayed adjacent to each other in one
>   row. This option is applicable only to bar and column charts.

Also try changing the Rotation & Inclination degrees, to get a better look.
Decrease wall thickness also.